# importing contactlist in phone

Tags: qt, mobile, symbian, pyqt4, pyside

I want to write an application that stores the contact list records, that user enters, so that the user will later be able to import them from within Symbian (and/or Android)  phone. What I'm asking is: is this possible and if so, what the format of stores should be in order to import records? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. What you need is the [Contacts API](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtmobility-1.2/contacts.html). You can find answers to your questions in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you, this is what i've looking for. I'll dig it up.